# EF Core implementation idea on dynamic SQL Server database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Let me describe the scenario: I have a database which has dynamic tables, and the columns and their datatypes are also dynamic.

In this scenario can I use EF Core?

If yes then please suggest some links for my better understanding, and if no then using which library can I handle this scenario?

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here?? Having a totally dynamic database, tables, columns seems like a really bad idea - design smells all around. If you really **must handle** such a situation, you probably need to fall back to lowest-level raw SQL and the ADO.NET data access library and handle it all yourself - good luck!

Comment: There's no such thing as "dynamic tables", columns or datatypes. All databases change over time. EF Core isn't a generic data access library (that's ADO.NET), it's an *ORM* - an **O**bject-to-**R**elational **M**apper. It's job is to map relational data to application objects. Application objects pretty fixed. All ORMs in .NET use ADO.NET to execute arbitrary queries and handle arbitrary results

Comment: BTW the question is too vague. All applications need to access data. All data changes. You may be able to work with an ORM just fine. Or perhaps a micro-ORM like Dapper is better, to execute raw SQL and map it to objects. Or perhaps you need to execute raw SQL and get the results with no processing as an ADO.NET DbDataReader or DataTable.

Comment: There are legit use cases if someone wants to use an sql database for persistency. After all, one of the biggest selling points of  nosql databases is that they are schema less and everything can be dynamic.

Comment: To answer the question, if everything is dynamic, ef core is useless. Ef core is supposed to be used when the schema is known at the design time. as @marc_s mentioned you will have to use low level SQL queries to access your data.